# Javascript library for node and broswer

Tags: node.js, websocket, browser

writing some simple JS library for node and browser that uses websockets. In browser environment we have WebSocket API built in, but for node we need a package. How to deal with this...how to install ws npm package when library is run on node?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as the two implementations (being the native WebSocket API and the external npm module) support the same protocol, it does not matter which websocket module you pick.

The commonly used package is [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws). WebSocket API and this package follow [RF 6455](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) for their protocol, which makes them interoperable.

Comment: But how to specify library need for installing ws when is running on node? Currently I get this error: ReferenceError: WebSocket is not defined....which is fine, cause there is no WebSocket API in Node. How to tell to install ws only if library is running on Node?